# FluentValidation that involves 2 properties in the object being validated

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I have a business rule that says that `PropertyA` should be a multiple of `PropertyB`.

As you see, the validation isn't taking care of a property alone, but needs to validate 2 interrelated properties. How do I make this using **FluentValidations**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Say you have an object like this:

```
class Data {
  public int PropertyA;
  public int PropertyB;
}
```

Then in the validator you can do something like this:

```
public class DataValidator : AbstractValidator<Data> {

  public DataValidator() {
    // 'x' in this case is the instance of the 'Data' class being validated
    //
    RuleFor(x => x).Must(HaveMultiplierRelationship);
  }

  private bool HaveMultiplierRelationship(Data d)
  {
    return (d.PropertyA % d.PropertyB) == 0;
  }
}
```

This method works well because you can chain multiple `Must` calls together to test a number of different aspects of the object in question.

Comment: It looks really elegant. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, FluentValidation is a pretty slick library.